# How can I backup my notes and highlights on iBooks? (pc user)

Tags: windows, books

I don't have a Mac and I want to do what's specified [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2560/is-there-a-way-to-export-my-highlighted-bookmarks-in-ibooks).

Is there a Linux/Windows app for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to export my highlighted bookmarks in iBooks?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2560/is-there-a-way-to-export-my-highlighted-bookmarks-in-ibooks)

Comment: @stuffe: Possibly, but all the answers there are out of date (e.g. link to non-working software, or solutions that are no loner applicable).

Comment: @any luck finding it?