# How to copy a book from iBooks with highlighting?

Tags: macos, icloud, books, dropbox, epub

I have a book on my iMac at work which has highlighting all over the book. But when I put the book in my Dropbox and open it on my MacBook at home there are no highlights. Is there a way to preserve the highlighting?

iBooks is the app that I use and I made all highlights with it.

iBooks version 1.5 on iMac 1.6 on MacBook

The book is .epub file

Comment: Please let us know which version(s) of macOS / OS X you use. Also, is the book you added highlights to an ePub?

Comment: You will find a lot of useful info regarding your question here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154561/how-do-i-collect-all-of-my-notes-and-highlights-from-ibooks

Answer (score 2):

I assume you added an ePub file to iBooks.app on your iMac and added highlightings there.

Yes, you can in fact sync your highlightings/notes/bookmarks between multiple devices running macOS and/or iOS.

---

Please follow these steps to sync your highlights:

**Prepare iMac**

1. On your iMac go to `System Preferences > iCloud`.
2. Make sure that you are **logged into** your **iCloud** account. If not, log in.
3. Depending on your version of macOS you need to **check** the check mark for `Documents & Settings`.
4. In **iBooks**.app sign in to the **same iCloud account** it you aren't already.
5. Make sure that the ePub file is the very same on both Macs.

**Prepare your MacBook**

1. Repeat the steps above that you did for your iMac.

**Sync your highlightings**

1. Reboot both Macs
2. Open the ePub in iBooks.app on your **iMac** and **add a note** or a bookmark.
3. **Close the ebook** in iBooks.app but leave iBooks.app running.
4. **Open** the ePub on your **MacBook** with iBooks.app. **Wait for** the highlightings/bookmarks/**notes to appear**. It may take a few minutes for the first time.
5. If they don't appear on your MacBook, add a new highlighting/bookmark.

---

**Please note**

If possible, you should run the same versions of macOS on both Macs. Also check for available software updates.

Using the **same Apple iCloud account** is necessary for the synchronization to work with **Apple's iBooks.app**. You can't use another cloud storage provider for this.

Unfortunately there is no other way to sync them other than to re-add your edits by hand.

Comment: Even though I can't make it like you described it. I voted you up because it's a good answer if you have the same apple account on both devices.